# how to continue the test in the loop, despite the error

Tags: java, junit, selenium-webdriver, testng

Is a test that performs a loop. Login details are retrieved from the database. Test if the password is incorrect is interrupted because WD does not find that item after logging He should click. How do the test is not interrupted when, for example, the fourth of the ten passwords turned out to be wrong only marked exception, and continued to be a test next?

I care for the example. 100 logins and passwords to catch those that are incorrect.

Piece of code:

```
driver.get(baseUrl + "a url");
AssertJUnit.assertEquals("assert text", driver.getTitle());
driver.findElement(By.id("login")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys(login);
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(password);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.triangle")).click();
```

If the login is unsuccessful you can click the button on the last line of code.
What to use? assertEquals? verifity? softAssert? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I get it? Add what your logic in the test cases. Three cases in three style.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;


public class StackOverFlow26116823 {

    private static String password = "s";
    private static String getPassword(){
        return password + "a";
    }

    @Test
    public void testFail() {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 100; i ++){
            assertEquals("a" , getPassword());
        }
    }


    @Test
    public void testLoopToSave() {
        List<AssertionError> errorS = new ArrayList<AssertionError>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 100; i ++){
            try{
                assertEquals("a" , getPassword());
            }catch(AssertionError e){
                errorS.add(e);
            }
        }
        assertTrue( getAllErrorMessageTrace(errorS) , errorS.size() == 0 );
    }

    private String getAllErrorMessageTrace(List<AssertionError> errorS) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "";
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoopJustCountAndLogging() {
        boolean errorFlag = false;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 100; i ++){
            try{
                assertEquals("a" , getPassword());
            }catch(AssertionError e){
                System.out.println( i + ": " + e.getMessage() );
                errorFlag = true;
            }
        }
        assertTrue( "Some errors that you can find in log. ", errorFlag);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try to explain what I mean.
Choose from the database logins and passwords. for example, 10 Among them are such which can not be logged. I want to catch those that are incorrect, but I also want to test executed for all downloaded from the database logins and passwords assigned to them. That is: choose a login and password, logs in, if the password is incorrect (can not login) saves them to a file such as excel or to the logs but do not interrupt the test only continue it for the next login and password until the entire list.

Comment: I prefer TestNG because easier to use in the parameters and generate a simple test report.

Comment: May be need some other check and make it run into other functions as you described.

Comment: Yes, maby. I use dataProvider and it solves my problem with this post. Thanks for the response.